# Microsoft Enterprise Library alternatives

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

Microsoft Enterprise Library has somewhat controversial feedback. Some developers like it, some say it is overengineered. Are there any alternatives to it? Both free and commercial.

Comment: There's lots of stuff in the EF.  Are there particular areas that you're looking for replacements (e.g. logging, data layer, etc.)?

Comment: In particular I'm looking for logging, exception handling, caching and security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an alternative that maps one to one to Enterprise Library.

[The Spring.NET Framework](http://www.springframework.net/) has some of the EL functionality.  It provides:

- [IoC container](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html)
- [Validation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/validation.html)
- [Data Access](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/spring-middle-tier.html)
- [Exception Handling](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-aspect-library.html#exception-aspect)

But Spring.NET also provides much more functionality and is a bigger architectural decision than EL (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

You will find a number of different libraries available, both commercially and Open Source, that tackle the same problems targeted by the Enterprise Library.
Some of them may do a better job than the Enterprise Library at solving a particular class of problems, while others may provide richer functionality.

The real advantage of Enterprise Library is that it offers  **a complete set of solutions that are deeply integrated with each other**.
These solutions are implemented as modules that can be used independently but can also **be combined together**, depending on the particular needs of the application.

I would recommend considering the Enterprise Library in two main scenarios:

- You need a particular piece of functionality that is not available in any other library (like Exception Handling)
- You plan to use multiple modules to solve a series of problems (like Logging and Exception Handling), in which case you can benefit from a unified configuration model and some nice tooling support around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Rockford Lhotka’s CSLA .NET framework](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/). Not sure how popular it is though.